# How can I tell Google Contacts to dial with the callto: instead of hangouts?

Tags: google-contacts

At work I have a Skype for Business installed as a softphone. I would like to be able to call Google contacts using this. However, when I call from inside Google contacts, it just goes ahead and dials using Hangouts. I don't like this, because using Hangouts to call real telephones costs me money, whereas Skype for Business doesn't.

Is there any way to configure Google contacts to call using Skype for Business instead of Hangouts?